Determining IV priced into convertible notes
I'm trying to determine the IV priced into convertible notes at the time they were issued. Ideally, using python.
Here are a list of the terms:

It is my understanding that for a simple convertible note (coupon, and maturation date), I can assume:

par value ($1,000) = <bond value> + <option value>

The bond value would be the principal discounted at some rate, as well as the sum of the coupons (also discounted at some rate). Which then allows me to solve for sigma in the option value:

<option value(sigma)> = $1,000 - <bond value>

That's easy enough, except the convertible notes I'm looking at have a few other terms which may or may not alter the bond value and/or the option value, and so it's out of my depth.

Holder can convert earlier than maturity date
Company can request redemption, if stock trades at 130% the conversion price, for 20 out of 30 days. The redemption request would result in the note holders converting.
Put Dates: On these specific dates, note holders can redeem the notes for principal + owed interest.

There is also one last twist to this:

Capped Calls, and their cost. I'm not sure if it makes sense to compute IV with this factored in, or to compute the imputed IV of the capped calls after the fact. It is my understanding that they are essentially bull call spreads, long at <conversion price> and short at <cap price>.. but the above terms make this more complicated.

